# Cannot get rid of breakpoint in JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize()

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints

I use `MyEclipse 8.6` + `Apache Tomcat 5.5.27` + `JRockit 1.6.0 05` for web development. Every time I start up Tomcat in debug mode from MyEclipse, it suspends on a `NullPointerException` in `JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize():96"`. The stack trace is only `Thread.run` (of course, finalizer):

```
protected synchronized void finalize() {
  if (OdbcApi.getTracer().isTracing()) {
    OdbcApi.getTracer().trace("Driver.finalize");
  }

  try {
    if (hDbc != 0L) {
      disconnect(hDbc);
      closeConnection(hDbc);
      hDbc = 0L;
   }
  } catch (SQLException localSQLException) {}
}
```

It is really annoying, seeing this hundreds of times every workday. I did not put this breakpoint here and I cannot disable it. I checked that exception breakpoints are off. Do you have any suggestion? How can a breakpoint "freeze" into the JVM?

Comment: Try to disable `Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions` Window->Prefs->Java->Debug

Comment: thanks a lot.. :-) please copy-paste your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to disable Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions Window->Prefs->Java->Debug

Answer (score 1):

If you can't turn off a breakpoint - it is a common problem in Eclipse - turning off ALL breakpoints always work. (doubled crosses button in breakpoints window)