# JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: not available

Tags: java

I am using eclipse to build Maven project. Whenever I tried to debug, a tab titled "JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: not available" appear and with in the tab the following massage "source not found" with a button stating "Edit source look up path" displayed.

Could any one explain what should I do to solve the problem?

P.S.this problem stopping me to perform any debugging to any problem

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223705/cannot-get-rid-of-breakpoint-in-jdbcodbcdriver-finalize

Comment: getting rid of that POS driver and using a real database (there's now a very nice embedded database in the JDK you can use for testing...) works wonders.

Comment: @jwenting Could you provide me with the step that I should follow?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like perhaps you have a breakpoint set either in JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() or perhaps you have an exception breakpoint (caught or uncaught) set, and an exception is being raised within JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize().

Eclipse is trying to present an editor to show you the breakpoint.  Since you didn't write JdbcOdbcDriver.java, and don't have its source in your IDE, eclipse is telling you to add it via the Run/Debug launch settings.  The reason you see "line: not available" is because the JdbcOdbcDriver.class was compiled (by Oracle) without debug enabled, so source line numbers are not available for debugging.

You can either see if you have a breakpoint set and uncheck or delete it it in the debug perspective's breakpoints view, or you can simply choose Run -> Resume to allow the program to continue past the breakpoint.

**Edit**

You can globally disable uncaught exception errors in your eclipse preferences.  The screenshot below is from eclipse 4.2.

[image: debug preferences without suspend-on-exception]

Comment: I have performed what you suggest but the problem still persist any other suggestion

Comment: Updated response with a preference setting you can try.  Unchecking that should prevent breakpoints on uncaught exceptions in your jdbc driver.